# API requests are undefined when live, but work on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am having trouble with a node.js/express application I am trying to run.
When running on localhost, the data I pass to the route is parsed and I am able to use req.body.message successfully. However on my live site, this only returns undefined. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

This is the node.js app I am using on both the localhost and the live server.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

router.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`message is ${req.body.message}`);
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", router);
const PORT = 3030;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server on " + PORT));
```

If I do a POST with "message":"hello", on my localhost, I get the response with the "message is hello", but on the live server I get "message is undefined".

Any advice appreciated, cheers.

Comment: The order of middleware is important in express. While on a cross-origin platform, you need to define your routes after the middleware configurations, or pass required middleware in router.post as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. When calling the live api, you *need* to include a trailing slash.

E.g. `examplewebsite.com/send` **will not work.** However, `examplewebsite.com/send/` **will work.**

I don't know enough about how servers work to explain this, but it solved my problem. I hope anyone else with this issue can benefit from my finding.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Try putting all this middleware before '/send' API end point. Also check console errors that will give you more information about error.

Comment: Rearranging them did not change anything, but thanks